# listview of images

Tags: android, android-listview

using listview i want to view the images in list. each row has one image

Comment: and elaborate the question properly.

Comment: Are you planning to use custom adapter? its quite possible with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would to the following:

- Write a custom ArrayAdapter for the Listview
- pass an Array of Images or ImageURLs to you Adapter
- Inflate the ListViewRows with you custom implementation - hence an image

I would recommend http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

As a starting point. Since you are not giving additional information, there is not much more to do for me - except writing the code for you....